# Can I improve speed in Hyper-V?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, nat, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, multi-core

I use Windows Server 2008 R2 (it is host) with Hyper-V and a guest running Ubuntu 12.04 LTC. It is my settings:

- RAM 32768
- Cores (virtual processes) 4. (I need 12)

I also use virtual hard drive with 2 TB

Please, tell me:

1) Do I increase speed, if I use real hard drive?

It is important to know that I use Ubuntu. It is installed on the virtual hard drive. I know that in virtual box I always mount disk to Ubuntu via NAT. So there are not difference between virtual hard drive and real hard drive.

2) How can I set 12 processors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do I increase speed, if I use real hard drive?

Yes, but it should not be relevant - 1-3%. Your main problem likely is that the hard disc is a hard disc which is just slow. It likeiy is not a larger RAID 10 of fast discs or an SSD.

- How can I set 12 processors?

Use a modern version of Hyper-V. Not an outdated one with this low limit. 2012 is current, 2012 R2 coming out in two weeks.

Comment: I think you are wrong. http://windowsnotes.ru/virtualization/snimaem-ogranichenie-na-4-logicheskix-processora-v-windows-server-2008-r2-hyper-v/

Comment: Just because you can manually hack away at the actual xml file doesn't mean you should. This would place you in an unsupported configuration - in ANY sort of production environment, you would not want to be running in this configuration.

Comment: Esactly. There are - besides the fact you are in territory without support - known and published reasons the loimnit was put that low. And then raised in later releases.